# In a chef cookbook, how to assigned erb templates based on role

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to chef and I have a question regarding the following.

I have two servers that both use nginx.  The only difference is that the config files are different.  I am using erb templates for the nginx config files.

I would imagine that I would need one cookbook with two erb filets in the templates directory.

So, lets say I have two roles server1 and server2 and in the runlist for the both is nginx.

How do I set things up so when using role 1 to use the config file for server1? Same goes for server2.

Any tutorials on this subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nginx cookbook at http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/nginx, presents an ideal solution to the problem.

You have only one cookbook and one config template. If you need to customize something, create a role and just overwrite the attributes in your role.

There's also a definition (nginx_site), so you can use it to put sites inside the same nginx instance, enabling you to maintain as many sites as you want with little trouble with the overall nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Define the roles for server 1 & server 2. In that use, override_attributes or default_attributes. For using this, you have to be pro-active in writing recipes itself. See the Precedence section in below link for attribute precedence

http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Attributes